# Power BI : Unable to connect to the data source undefined

Tags: powerbi

Within Power BI (On cloud) console, the datasets screen is showng errors in form of alert icon, in detail the error for all of them is :

```
Something went wrong
Unable to connect to the data source undefined.
Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details.
Underlying error code: -2147467259 Table: <TABLE_NAME>.
Underlying error message: AnalysisServices: The following system error occurred: 
DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult: -2147467259
Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourceKind: AnalysisServices
Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourcePath: <path1>;<path2>
Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Reason: DataSource.Error
Cluster URI: WABI-SOUTH-CENTRAL-US-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Activity ID: 259c4fc7-dde9-449b-b108-9498b001ea25
Request ID: 56d4ee25-b539-4c05-8cd4-24b894507475
Time: 2019-06-13 12:12:51Z
```

I already reviewed gateway/ Analysis services but seems to be OK, Any idea what additional to review?

Answer (score 2):

You may check the different privacy level settings in Power BI Desktop and Power BI Service. Make sure you have the same privacy level security.

Answer (score 1):

Check Power BI gateway logs. For example, I received the same error message. Log information showed connectivity issue to SQL. I checked the server, and named pipes was disabled in client protocols. Since the report data source was configured by server name, connectivity could not work. Enabling it resolved the issue.